# how to install kubernetes on ubuntu offline

Tags: kubernetes, offline

I have to install kubernetes v1.13.7 on ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS in Internal network environment.

I can use docker and USB device.

actually, I can't download files through internet directly.

for one thing, I installed APIserver / controller / scheduler / etcd / coredns / proxy / flannel through docker load command.

but now, I should install kubeadm / kubelet / kubectl but I didn't install these.

how can I install kubernetes?

let me know your experience or websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is step-by-step [instruction](https://gist.github.com/onuryilmaz/89a29261652299d7cf768223fd61da02#download-kubernetes-rpms)

As for the kubernetes part, you can download packages from the online workstation

```
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/pool/e6aef7b2b7d9e5bd4db1e5747ebbc9f1f97bbfb8c7817ad68028565ca263a672-kubectl-1.6.0.x86_64.rpm
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/pool/af8567f1ba6f8dc1d43b60702d45c02aca88607b0e721d76897e70f6a6e53115-kubelet-1.6.0.x86_64.rpm
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/pool/e7a4403227dd24036f3b0615663a371c4e07a95be5fee53505e647fd8ae58aa6-kubernetes-cni-0.5.1.x86_64.rpm
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/pool/5116fa4b73c700823cfc76b3cedff6622f2fbd0a3d2fa09bce6d93329771e291-kubeadm-1.6.0.x86_64.rpm
```

and then just copy it over to your offline server via internal network

```
scp <folder_with_rpms>/*.rpm <user>@<server>:<path>/<to>/<remote>/<folder>
```

Lastly, install packages

```
yum install -y *.rpm
systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
```

Comment: This is for Centos as packages are rpm, is there a way to get deb packages for Ubuntu?